# Facebook app ... check whether previously liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing a Facebook tab app, it doesn't require any authorization. I give an offer to users who like the page. What I want is to check whether they have previously liked the page so the offer can't be abused by unliking and liking again.

I use the signed request to get whether the user has liked the page:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
```

Signed request doesn't seem to provide any information about when the page was liked first or how many times the current user has liked the page.

I'll appreciate any suggestions/solutions on how to achieve this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do using only the Facebook API. They do not provide a "like history" method to see if a user has previously liked an object. As far as the API is concerned, a "like" is a boolean value; Either it is true or it is false.

If you want to check that a user is not liking then unliking your page repeatedly, you'll have to record this activity on your own server (possibly in a DB of sorts). You still won't be able to prevent a user from liking/unliking the page continuously, but you will be able to limit the effect of that "like" in your application logic: If you already have a record of this user liking the page, don't provide them with an additional offer.

Comment: But without authorization do I get any sort of unique ID/parameter which I can reference the users with?

Comment: once a user likes the page you'll get a signed_request... the user ID is inside.

Comment: @Lix: Since when do you get the user id without the user connecting to the app first?

Comment: @CBroe - Ever since I've been working with their API really... You can get the user_id from the [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) or even from the results of the [`edge.create` event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). Both require the user to "like" the URL though - so there *is* some level of "connection" there...

Comment: The sign request I'm getting has `page(id, liked, admin)` and `user(country, locale, age)`... it's the same whether user has liked the page or not. I can't see any user ID in the signed request. What am I doing wrong?